# Table cell width of 1px, table width of 1440px

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

I wish to create a table with 1440 columns. each column will represent a minute of the day.

My goal is to show what was happening each minute of the day by setting the background color of the cell with PHP.

Before I can do that I have to try get my 1440 minutes of the day to fit onto the screen.
Ideally the table will be 1440 pixels wide, again one for each minute.

How can I format my table to have cells 1 pixel wide so that the entire table is just 1440 pixels wide?

My syntax is:

```
<table border=0 style="border-collapse:collapse;empty-cells: show;">
    <tr>
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 1440; $i++) { ?>
    <td style="width:1px; background-color:green;"></td>
    <?php } ?>
    </tr>

    <tr >
        <td colspan="120"><font size=2>6</td>
        <td colspan="120"><font size=2>8</td>
        <td colspan="120"><font size=2>10</td>
        <td colspan="120"><font size=2>12</td>
        <td colspan="120"><font size=2>14</td>
        <td colspan="120"><font size=2>16</td>
        <td colspan="120"><font size=2>18</td>
        <td colspan="120"><font size=2>20</td>
        <td colspan="120"><font size=2>22</td>
        <td colspan="120"><font size=2>24</td>
        <td colspan="120"><font size=2>02</td>
        <td colspan="120"><font size=2>04</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I understand this solution is ugly and using inline style etc just showing where I am currently.

Any help appreciated. If there is advice on how better to do this please let me know.

Comment: Apart of bad solution (performance of the browser would be the question) you can set `width: 1440px` for the table and make sure that all your cells have `margin: 0; padding: 0`. Try not to mix CSS and HTML4 tags (like `<font>`). Also use style sheets instead of putting all the `width`s and `background-color`s in each `<td>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if the following solution works for you.

```
    <table border=0 style="border-collapse:collapse;empty-cells: show; width:1440px;table-layout:fixed;">
    <tr >
<td colspan="120" style="background-color:green;"><font size=2>6</td>
<td colspan="120" style="background-color:green;"><font size=2>8</td>
<td colspan="120" style="background-color:green;"><font size=2>10</td>
<td colspan="120" style="background-color:green;"><font size=2>12</td>
<td colspan="120" style="background-color:green;"><font size=2>14</td>
<td colspan="120" style="background-color:green;"><font size=2>16</td>
<td colspan="120" style="background-color:green;"><font size=2>18</td>
<td colspan="120" style="background-color:green;"><font size=2>20</td>
<td colspan="120" style="background-color:green;"><font size=2>22</td>
<td colspan="120" style="background-color:green;"><font size=2>24</td>
<td colspan="120" style="background-color:green;"><font size=2>02</td>
<td colspan="120" style="background-color:green;"><font size=2>04</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note that I have used table-layout:fixed here.

Link to [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3W7W/)

Answer (score 0):

Kind of old, but for the next person that stumbles on this:

```
<style>
/* Collapse the Table borders */
table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
  empty-cells: show; 
}
/* set the size of the cells */
td{
  background-color:green;
  height:1px;
  width:1px;
}
/* just to give us something to look at
set every other one to a different color */
td:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
</style>
<!-- Construct a table to demonstrate the styles-->
<table></table>
<script>
for(var r=1; r>=0; r--){
    $('table').append('<tr></tr>');
}
for(var c = 1440; c>=0; c--){
    $('tr').append('<td title="'+c+'"></td>');
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5beorgve/2/
(tested in Chrome)

Still doesn't explain why mine doesn't work.